# Python-alike shutil module on Ruby

Tags: ruby, shutil

Python has a module `shutil` that has methods for copying and moving files. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html

What would be the equivalent for Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up [`FileUtils`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html).

It has similar methods as shutil for working with files (copy recursively, move,  copy while preserving or not preserving file attributes etc.)